# RedirectToAction throws 400 error in IE10

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-10, redirecttoaction

I have an ASP.Net MVC3 site using RedirectToAction like so:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", interstitialController,
                        new { userName = model.logInInfo.UserName, redirectString = redirectUrl, authToken = login.authenticationToken, reason = login.reason, status = login.status, provider = login.provider });
```

For some reason this is causing IE10 to generate this as a request:

```
https://site.com/(F(7vkS9Als2GF4acdwa9JNTwHsOkeFIsGcdMGU-FIT0X1IC3UwpkeZrPvTp1WmCbC7aY890yhpaeS4dadGjjUrym9Z_UOHYUUezRjD_buWV8pJU35yl2MHLz_CqzpJx65UyW5qDYdBJ8RMVj5kp02eaKzhX2--JcFvwPsYKeGk11t5MHWU4sbnFYw7keYlAuB5p4_JSVnn99SS28M8wWjQPNzw89G5qXwFRyrCYgIDDrWUUsefofkfEB66gIF2Abet0))/Interstitial/Index?userName=user.name%40earthlink.net&redirectString=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com%2Fcos_auth%2Fauthenticate.asp%3F_auth_token%3DPTZPGf5FDdVAtkXRXRd1piW5jTYSmjyraiQ79LEvrPsaf4kNDQLbJW%252bG5vZtRnSOZ50mLVm%252frF7Ne16uwQVXOOsnBzSeXj9RIUaEIpjmtFCUWOVDEldrVpIL6KBJasJ%252bac2pzS1oSKAqAK2kywt869NGQdWDM7u0%252fRHVikatRIHv8SpXiyz94eeaBEraKAnz%26persist%3D1&authToken=PTZPGf5FDdVAtkXRXRd1piW5jTYSmjyraiQ79LEvrPsaf4kNDQLbJW%2BG5vZtRnSOZ50mLVm%2FrF7Ne16uwQVXOOsnBzSeXj9RIUaEIpjmtFCUWOVDEldrVpIL6KBJasJ%2Bac2pzS1oSKAqAK2kywt869NGQdWDM7u0%2FRHVikatRIHv8SpXiyz94eeaBEraKAnz&status=Success&provider=COS
```

This should look like this:

```
https://site.com/Interstitial/Index?userName=user.name%40earthlink.net&redirectString=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com%2Fcos_auth%2Fauthenticate.asp%3F_auth_token%3DPTZPGf5FDdVAtkXRXRd1piW5jTYSmjyraiQ79LEvrPsaf4kNDQLbJW%252bG5vZtRnSOZ50mLVm%252frF7Ne16uwQVXOOsnBzSeXj9RIUaEIpjmtFCUWOVDEldrVpIL6KBJasJ%252bac2pzS1oSKAqAK2kywt869NGQdWDM7u0%252fRHVikatRIHv8SpXiyz94eeaBEraKAnz%26persist%3D1&authToken=PTZPGf5FDdVAtkXRXRd1piW5jTYSmjyraiQ79LEvrPsaf4kNDQLbJW%2BG5vZtRnSOZ50mLVm%2FrF7Ne16uwQVXOOsnBzSeXj9RIUaEIpjmtFCUWOVDEldrVpIL6KBJasJ%2Bac2pzS1oSKAqAK2kywt869NGQdWDM7u0%2FRHVikatRIHv8SpXiyz94eeaBEraKAnz&status=Success&provider=COS
```

It works fine on IE10 in compatibility mode, but not in non-compatibility mode.  Not sure what is causing this.  As you can see, it is inserting some garbage into the request that is causing it to fail.  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: That garbage looks like what happens in cookieless sessions. What happens if you change your web.config to have `<forms cookieless="UseCookies"...`?

Comment: http://nuget.org/packages/App_BrowsersUpdate

Comment: Thanks @WiktorZychla, I am trying this in our next release cycle.

Comment: Will post this as an answer if you report it solves your issue.

Comment: We had our rollout yesterday, I was hoping for the best because this is the only semi-related issue I could find, but no luck.  Thanks for finding that tho.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnHubbard, I am considering trying to change to a RedirectToRoute but I wont be able to try for a couple weeks probably.  I noticed it doesn't have the correct route at all ours should be /Interstitial/SITE/Index?params=values or /Interstitial/SITE?params=values  I am hoping that if I changed it to point to the named route instead it will get the correct controller from there.  Unfortunately this is not broken in our dev environment so I can't even test it.  Look forward to hearing if you find a response.

Comment: Hm, guess I accidentally deleted my previous comment. We've tried both changing the forms authentication config to force cookies and we've updated the browser definitions for IE10 but no luck. Our failure is in ASPX so I don't think it's an MVC thing.

Comment: For us this was indeed a login issue and changing the web.config to force it to use cookies fixed it for us. If this is just a redirect, not sure if the web.config will help there. Good luck!

Comment: @MikeSmithDev This worked! I finally got it into a release.  Thank you so much, if you want to post it as the answer I will mark it when I see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That garbage looks like what happens in cookieless sessions.

If you change your web.config to have `<forms cookieless="UseCookies"`, it will get rid of that stuff.

From [MSDN FormsAuthentication.CookieMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.cookiemode.aspx):

> The CookieMode property reflects the value for the cookieless
>   attribute of the forms configuration element. The CookieMode property
>   determines whether the FormsAuthenticationTicket value will be stored
>   in a session cookie in the browser or stored in the QueryString
>   property.

Comment: I set this and the following below at the same time, one of these fixed it.
    <system.web>
        <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </system.web>

Comment: @Miva oh yeah that can be needed too :)