# What are there hashes in URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

Perplexed here on how/why the ASP.NET MVC4 URL has hashes in them.

Deployed to the test server -- URL looks normal like this:
http://testweb1.me.local/Admin/Permission/AddPermission

When deployed to production server -- this is what I get:
http://prodweb1.me.local/Admin/(F(QlUC0Nb2vhAGUhEJK1QW7kkwckxhSoQ8LqBuDkZiOzVzmuO9SGyBz2i2nKn_zPYUZbC-lfvKGkZUBJNnNKnNa_O79kfZQ1mkGZmpaJS3D1w1))/Permission/AddPermission

Must be something in IIS 7, but what?

Comment: Cookieless sessions will do this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15706382/1810243

Comment: That was it too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228704/ie10-injects-token-into-net-mvc-links Thanks @MikeSmithDev (might be  worthwhile to link this issue to the other 2)