# IE 11 and cookieless session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I have my asp.net mvc application running on 2 servers. On one of the servers only IE 11 thinks I'm using sessionless cookies and shows the id in the URL. Not sure where to start to trouble shoot this. I don't have a problem with the other server, the other browsers, or IE 11 when accessing the site on the other server. Project, web.config and IIS settings all look the same. Please help.

Comment: Did you specify in the web.config [to not allow cookieless sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16152427/1810243)?

Comment: My web.config as well as the machine.config did not have any sessionState information set however the correct settings are in IIS. Now I've tried to add that section into the web.config and it seems to do nothing to help my problem.

Comment: Can you maybe update the question with the web.config entries where you are specifying for no-cookieless sessions? It will help in diagnosing issue.

Comment: Why should I need to set the <sessionState> in any config at all? Session information should be coming from IIS when not overridden. Also, Chrome and Firefox work as expected. Very confusing situation.

Comment: The default value for cookies in forms auth is `UseDeviceProfile` which means: "ASP.NET determines whether to use cookies based on System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities setting. If the setting indicates that the browser or device supports cookies, cookies are used; otherwise, **an identifier is used in the query string.**" It's not just an IE11 issue. ASP.NET does a number of things by default that you may not necessarily want or expect.

Comment: So is it the servers inability to determine what my IE 11 is capable off? Since my last comment, I've gone on 3 other servers and used various versions of IE and all can get to the website and use the session correctly. Would your suggestion be to put the same settings that I see in IIS copied into the web.config? Is there some config for Browser Capabilities I should change? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like one of your servers isn't fully up-to-date with patches or has defined a custom browser caps file.  If this is a 4.x application pool, make sure you have installed ASP.NET 4.5 on the machine.  If this is a 2.x application pool, you may have to install the hotfixes manually.

See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx for more information.  Pay attention especially to the part about "aspnet_regbrowsers -i", which will force any custom browser caps file on the machine to be destroyed and overwritten with the default (fixed) one in the framework.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change just one line in your config file like
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE; then problem solve.

Comment: Don't think that you can use this in asp.net

Comment: It's for Codeingnater FW in php.Not for asp.net.