# Don't no what happened and generate Url like this http://localhost:6143/(S(rgiplqpu3vuifxq2f5ngncre))/index.aspx

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Don't no what happened and generate Url like this http://localhost:6143/(S(rgiplqpu3vuifxq2f5ngncre))/index.aspx

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Arindam Nayak That would be a great *answer* to the question.

Comment: Simiar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15706382/1810243

Answer (score 2):

You have changed session storage to cookieless, that made the session identifier to be present in URL. – MSDN LINK - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: m all ready use session cookieless but all pages have same string on ervery refresh generate new string .

Comment: It would be better to reframe your question, as you can see, you are not clear about you question - down votes followed by closing of question. When I answered, that is totally based on oneliner question, so update your scenario and expectation.