# generate Url like this http://localhost:6143/(S(rgiplqpu3vuifxq2f5ngncre))/index.aspx and every refresh string will pe change

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Don't no what happened and generate Url like this http://localhost:6143/(S(rgiplqpu3vuifxq2f5ngncre))/index.aspx m need only simple url like //localhost:6143/index.aspx but my all pages same like this string and every refresh it string change.i don't find the location where its string generate in project.

Comment: Could be session state (if you have  `...sessionState cookieless=true...` in your web.config.) also I think ID format is different...

Comment: did you wrote `HTTPModule ` ?? i mean Modules ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't no what happened and generate Url like this http://localhost:6143/(S(rgiplqpu3vuifxq2f5ngncre))/index.aspx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636573/dont-no-what-happened-and-generate-url-like-this-http-localhost6143-srgipl)

Comment: Yes in my case sessionstate=true in config file i update cookieless =false and solve my problem thanks Ganesh_Devlekar